# Android Edittext Sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

Can someone please help me edit the following code so that it saves the info typed into the edittext and then once the app is relaunched it will automatically display the text that was saved in the edittext field. I have tried SharedPreferences tutorials but so far I have not been able to get it working.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtLink;
Button btnOpenLink;
String defaultLink;
String secondLink;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String Name = "nameKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

defaultLink = "http://";
secondLink = ".whatver.com";

txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
btnOpenLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String server = txtLink.getText().toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Name, server);
    editor.commit();
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(server)){
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,webactivity.class);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(defaultLink+server+secondLink));
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your server name.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
});
}

}
```

Comment: Please paste the Preferences code you tried.

Comment: I tried everything in this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Whatever you tried please paste that.

Comment: I have updated it with one thing that i have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by calling this

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    txtLink.setText(sharedpreferences.getString(Name, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify the stored preferences and load  them if any avaliable, after that display them in the textview

## Example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

defaultLink = "http://";
secondLink = ".whatver.com";

txtLink = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
btnOpenLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

checkIfPreferencesAvaliable();

if(defaultLink!=null && secondLink!=null){
    txtLink.setText(defaultLink+secondLink);
}

defaultLink = "http://";
secondLink = ".whatver.com";

void checkIfPreferencesAvaliable(){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    defaultLink = preferences.getStr("mydefaultLink", null);
    secondLink = preferences.getStr("mysecondLink", null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()`, check if you have already have values in your preferences-

```
String savedVal = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(Name, null);

if(savedVal == null){ //This means you don't have the saved values in your prefs file
//Do whatever you want to
} else{
//Use "savedVal" anyway you want
}
```

Comment: I am new to this, can you show me where to put that and how will this load the saved string?

Comment: In your onCreate() method paste the code I provided and if you want to set it ina TextView you can set that using "savedVal".

Comment: What I would like it to do is

if(savedVal == null){ do nothing
} else{
show it in the editText field
}

How can I make that happen?

Comment: if(savedVal == null) you can show the empty edittext.